# date_create_from_format return false

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to conver a string into a date, but apparently the format I given is not accepted by `date_create_from_format`, I did:

```
$search_date = trim('09/26/2019 - 09/27/2019');
$search_date = explode('-', $search_date);

echo $search_date[0];
$date_start = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', $search_date[0]);
var_dump($date_start);
```

this return:

```
09/26/2019 bool(false)
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on bool in [...][...]:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
```

looking at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) I can see as format:

```
>d and j    Day of the month, 2 digits with or without leading zeros
>m and n    Numeric representation of a month, with or without leading zeros
>Y  A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
```

and my date is actually: `09/26/2019`, what am i overlooking?

Comment: _“and my date is actually: 09/26/2019”_ - use var_dump instead of echo, even for debug outputs of such “simple” values - that wraps the output in double quotes, and shows you the length of the string as well, and thereby makes it easier to spot issues like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple problem of when you explode with `-`, there are spaces left in the date parts, so change the conversion to trim the value prior to converting it...

```
$date_start = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', trim($search_date[0]));
```

gives...

```
class DateTime#3 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(26) "2019-09-26 10:03:06.000000"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(13) "Europe/London"
}
```

Comment: I though the first `trim` should be be enough, but it's not. Thanks very much

Comment: trim only removes leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @faccenda or make `$search_date = explode(' - ', $search_date)`, if you are sure about the input.